# SQL Server Dúvidas ao Somar turno 3 (SUM)

Tags: sql, servidor

Como fazer uma soma (SUM) do turno 3 de uma empresa e organizar por dia? O problema é que o turno 3 acaba no dia seguinte (começa as 22hrs e acaba as 6hrs do dia seguinte), então estou tentando fazer uma exceção somente ao turno 3 que no dia atual desconsidere os valores obtidos antes das 6 da manhã e some das 22 horas até as 6 da manhã do dia seguinte.
Segue abaixo o script que eu já fiz e o resultado obtido
No resultado obtido o Turno 3 de hoje (dia 14 já está com dado produzido, porém esse dado deveria ser do turno 3 de ontem)

```
SELECT 
STR(DAY(E3TimeStamp),2) + '/' + STR(MONTH(E3TimeStamp),1) + '/' + STR(YEAR(E3TimeStamp),4) AS Data,
Maquina AS Maquina,
Parametro AS Código,
ROUND(sum(Metrica),2) AS 'Metrica Total' ,
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 1 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 01',
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 2 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 02',
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 3 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 03'
FROM Tab_Dados_Escolha
GROUP BY 
YEAR(E3TimeStamp), MONTH(E3TimeStamp),DAY(E3TimeStamp), Maquina, Parametro
```

Resultado obtido do script acima:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado que deveria ocorrer (Turno 03 foi somado ao dia anterior, pois ainda não iniciou hoje):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não cumprimente, não agradeça e não assine as publicações. Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá,
a consulta abaixo deve trazer o que você está precisando

```
select Dataturno,
       Maquina AS Maquina,
       Parametro AS Código,
       ROUND(sum(Metrica),2) AS 'Metrica Total' ,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 1 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 01',
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 2 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 02',
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 3 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 03'
 from (
 select cast( iif( turno = 3 and datepart(hour, E3TimeStamp) < 6, dateadd( -1, day, E3TimeStamp ), E3TimeStamp ) as date ) as Dataturno,
       Maquina AS Maquina,
       Parametro AS Código,
       Turno,
       Metrica
  from Tab_Dados_Escolha
) x
group by 
    Dataturno, Maquina, Parametro,
```

Vou explicar o que fiz.
na linha 12: se o turno = 3 e a hora < 6, eu considero a E3TimeStamp como dia anterior.
Assim você vai contar todo o turno, como dia anterior.
Usei um cast, para trazer somente a data, e não precisar pegar o dia, mes e ano.

Não tenho como testar, mas se der algum erro e não conseguir resolver, me avise que tento te ajudar.

Comment: Ok, desculpe... não vai se repetir.

Answer (score 0):

> O problema é que o turno 3 acaba no dia seguinte (começa as 22hrs e
> acaba as 6hrs do dia seguinte)

Para resolver esse problema, considere que a data `datetime` deve ser manipulada de forma  a "parecer" que pertence ao final do dia anterior. Após essa manipulação, você pode executar sua consulta que obterá o resultado esperado. Fiz um exemplo no Fiddle que está disponível neste link [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/525d3/2).

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tab_dados_escolha (
    Maquina varchar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS DEFAULT NULL NULL,
    Metrica decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
    E3TimeStamp datetime DEFAULT NULL NULL,
    Turno int DEFAULT NULL NULL,
    Parametro int NULL
);

INSERT INTO tab_dados_escolha (Maquina,Metrica,E3TimeStamp,Turno,Parametro) VALUES
     (N'ESC_RET',10,'2021-05-13 05:00:00.0',3,125),
     (N'ESC_RET',7,'2021-05-14 03:00:00.0',3,125),
     (N'ESC_RET',22,'2021-05-13 10:00:00.0',1,125),
     (N'ESC_RET',15,'2021-05-13 16:00:00.0',2,125),
     (N'ESC_RET',2,'2021-05-13 23:00:00.0',3,125),
     (N'ESC_RET',4,'2021-05-14 23:00:00.0',3,125);
```

**Consulta 1**:

```
select * from tab_dados_escolha
```

**[Resultado](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/525d3/2/0)**:

| Maquina | Metrica | E3TimeStamp | Turno | Parametro |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ESC_RET | 10 | 2021-05-13T05:00:00Z | 3 | 125 |
| ESC_RET | 7 | 2021-05-14T03:00:00Z | 3 | 125 |
| ESC_RET | 22 | 2021-05-13T10:00:00Z | 1 | 125 |
| ESC_RET | 15 | 2021-05-13T16:00:00Z | 2 | 125 |
| ESC_RET | 2 | 2021-05-13T23:00:00Z | 3 | 125 |
| ESC_RET | 4 | 2021-05-14T23:00:00Z | 3 | 125 |

### A Solução

**Consulta 2**:

```
with tab_dados_escolha_corrigido as
(
    Select * from tab_dados_escolha
    except
    Select Maquina, Metrica, E3TimeStamp, Turno, Parametro
      from tab_dados_escolha
     where DatePart(hour,E3TimeStamp) < 6
    Union
    Select Maquina, Metrica, cast(cast(cast(E3TimeStamp-1 as date) as varchar) + ' 23:59:00' as datetime) as E3TimeStamp, Turno, Parametro
      from tab_dados_escolha
     where DatePart(hour,E3TimeStamp) < 6
)
SELECT 
  convert(varchar,E3TimeStamp,103) AS Data,
  Maquina AS Maquina,
  Parametro AS Código,
  ROUND(sum(Metrica),2) AS 'Metrica Total' ,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 1 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 01',
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 2 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 02',
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Turno = 3 THEN Metrica ELSE 0 END),2) As 'Metrica Turno 03'
FROM tab_dados_escolha_corrigido
GROUP BY convert(varchar,E3TimeStamp,103), Maquina, Parametro
```

**[Resultado](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/525d3/2/1)**:

| Data | Maquina | Código | Metrica Total | Metrica Turno 01 | Metrica Turno 02 | Metrica Turno 03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/05/2021 | ESC_RET | 125 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| 13/05/2021 | ESC_RET | 125 | 46 | 22 | 15 | 9 |
| 14/05/2021 | ESC_RET | 125 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 4 |

### A ideia

A ideia foi utilizando lógica dos conjuntos da seguinte forma:
Pegue todos os registros da tabela com exceção `except` daquele cuja hora é inferior a 6 horas.
O resultado, faça uma união com todos os registros que foram excluídos com o `except`, mas manipulamos a data para passar a pertencer ao dia anterior `cast(cast(cast(E3TimeStamp-1 as date) as varchar) + ' 23:59:00' as datetime) as E3TimeStamp`, dessa forma o forçamos a data a apontar para o dia no qual o campo ´metrica´ deve ser somado.

### **Comando With ... As**

O comando `with tab_dados_escolha_corrigido as ()` permite criar o que é chamado de CTE (*common table expression*) ou expressão de tabela comum que é uma espécie de tabela temporária definida no escopo de execução de uma única instrução SELECT. No seu caso, você poderia criar um `view` chamada `tab_dados_escolha_corrigido`.

### **Convert**

Foi utilizado o `convert(varchar,E3TimeStamp,103)` para tornar o resultado da data no formato que você evidenciou na sua consulta original.